# How can I do redirect 301 http in a Compojure/Luminus app?

Tags: redirect, clojure, compojure, ring, luminus

I have an action in an Compojure/Luminus app:

```
(defn my-page1 [id]
  (layout/render "my_page.html" 
    (let 
      [item (db/get-single-item {:id id})]

      ; this throws an exception
      ; if .....
      ; redirect "fdsfdsfd" :status 301

      { :my-item item})))
```

How can I check some condition and if it's true, then do a redirect to a  new url with the http status 301? 
Where should I put in the my code and how can I do a redirect?

Comment: `get-single-item` throws an exception when the item is not found or it returns `nil`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `layout/render` function returns a full HTTP 200 ring response with HTML body content. You need to return a redirect response instead of the response produced by `layout/render` function:

```
(defn my-page1 [id]
  (if (some-condition)
    (layout/render ...)
    (ring.util.response/redirect "http://elsewhere.com/" 301)))
```